# Mapping a foreign key with a different name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have the following model:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UseraccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Useraccount Useraccount { get; set; }
}
```

The useraccountId is my foreign key showing to my useraccount entity/model. 
The entity framework can map this foreign key to the virtual property because it removes the "Id", so "useraccountId" becomes "useraccount" -> mapping to "Useraccount".
What if I want to rename the foreign key "useraccountId" to "creatorId"? How can I now tell the Entity framework to map this foreign key to the virtual Useraccount property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ForeignKey` attribute.

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public virtual Useraccount Useraccount { get; set; }
}
```